# django pagination filter - according to one row but getting error

Tags: python, django

I have 1 model name "Post" in which i have multiple rows one of them is 'cat'(row-category)

I just wanna filter data that if my url contains cat=1 so it show all the cat 1 listings

My Views.py

I tried this but getting error. please guide me what i am doing wrong?

```
def listing(request,post_cat):
    var_cat =  get_object_or_404(Post, cat=post_cat)

    user_list = Post.objects.all(var_cat)
    paginator = Paginator(user_list, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page') 

    try:
        users = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        users = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'ads/listing.html', { 'users': users })
```

getting error in my console:

```
  user_list = Post.objects.all(var_cat)
                                        ^
                                        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: this error in my console: user_list = Post.objects.all(var_cat)                                         ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: perhaps you are mixing tabs and white spaces in indentation

Comment: no i checked everything is ok you can see my code

Comment: @Cathrine Which IDE you are using?

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi sublime text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates, you have an indentation error. It is probably caused by a mix of tabs and spaces.

Go to:

```
View -> Indentation
```

It should show:

1. Indent using spaces [x]
2. Tab width: 2

Select:

```
Convert Indentation to Tabs
```

Then Select:

- Tab width: 4
- Convert Indentation to Spaces

You are done.

Comment: i think your code is working now am getting other error: Using the URLconf defined in mlx.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Comment: can u guide me how i should configure my urls.py

Comment: i tried this     path('listing?post_cat=<int:post_cat>/', views.listing, name='listing'),

Comment: i fixed it thanks for your help. the problem was weird i didn't face this kind of issue before.

Comment: I think it should be like this path('listing/<int:post_cat>/', views.listing, name='listing')

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: yeah i did the same,